# How can I but this list of database values in my SelectListItem and DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I’m trying to use the following approach to creating a list from my database then accessing them in my view. Here’s what I’ve been trying…

```
var rTypeList = from r in db.Rubrics where r.DepartmentID == 2 select r;
var selectedRubrics = typeList.Select(r => r.Category);
IList <String> rubricsList = selectedRubrics.ToList();

IList<SelectListItem> iliSLI = new List<SelectListItem>();

SelectListItem selectedrubrics = new SelectListItem();
selectedrubrics.Text = "Choose An Option";
selectedrubrics.Value = "1";
selectedrubrics.Selected = true;

iliSLI.Add(selectedrubrics);

ViewData["Options"] = iliSLI;
```

Then in my view I have:  `@Html.DropDownList("Options")`

This gets my list started but how can I get the values from this list…            `IList <String> rubricsList = selectedRubrics.ToList();`… and add them to my DropDown list?

Comment: you have most of the pieces in place already. which part confuses you?is it rendering the dropdown or getting values to your controller?

Comment: I want to add IList <String> rubricsList = selectedRubrics.ToList() to my IList<SelectListItem> iliSLI = new List<SelectListItem>() collection.

Comment: you want to concatenate lists?

Comment: Thanks I converted the database value to a list of string then used a for loop to add to the SelectListItem collection.Yasser's code gave me the multiple new SelectLisItem idea.  I looped through the values adding new SelectListItems.  Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost figured out the difficult part of your problem.

[Here](http://yassershaikh.com/introduction-to-dropdownlist-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor/) is an explanation...

At the controller side, you need to have a List of SelectListItem type. I have passed this list to my ViewBag.DropDownData, here you could have passed it to your model instead, but I am trying to keep it as simple as possible. So you pass the list to a viewbag.

**Controller code**

```
var myList = new List<SelectListItem>
{
new SelectListItem {Text = "Yasser", Value = "YS"},
new SelectListItem {Text = "Vaibhav", Value = "VS"},
new SelectListItem {Text = "Ramanjit", Value = "RS"}
};

ViewBag.DropDownData = myList;
```

Now in the view using the @Html.DropDownListFor() method, the first argument should be a string/int (depending upon your value) declared in your model which will be later be used when data is posted back to the controller. The second parameter is the List we just prepared, in case if you are using a model then simply pass your model here instead.

**Razor View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ValueSelected, ViewBag.DropDownData as List<SelectListItem>)
```

There that’s it. Your dropdown is ready to go :), here’s the ouput of my code:

**Output**

[image]

Hope this helps.